# Can't append text to specific position in C++

Tags: c++, string, file, io

I'm trying to **add text to a specific position** in C++ with `ofstream` and `seekp`. However, it always append to the end of the file.

I've **alredy tried** to write with `file.write(string, len)`, but the result is so the same.

My code:

```
void printHistory(int media, time_t timestamp){
    ofstream file("history.json", ios::app);
    long initial_pos = file.tellp();
    file.seekp(initial_pos-3);
    file << ", [" << timestamp << "," << media << "]]\n}";
    file.close();
}
```

Comment: Sure the `operator<<()` doesn't care about the `seekp()` call. You have to use `file.write()` instead. But take care: that overwrites everything at that position.

Comment: I've tried this already. The result is so the same...

Comment: Post a [MCVE] please, that everyone can reproduce your problem.

Comment: I'm not trying to add to the end. I'm trying to add to the end minus 3, but, however, the program always append at the end.

Comment: @LuizGuilhermeFonsecaRosa *the program always append at the end*  That's because you're opening the `ofstream` with `ios::app`, [which means](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/open/):  *All output operations happen at the end of the file, appending to its existing contents.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like:

```
fstream fs ("fred.txt", ios::in | ios::out);
fs.seekg (0, ios::end);
streamoff filesize = fs.tellg();
fs.seekp (filesize - 3);    // locate yourself 3rd char from end.
fs.write( "X", 1 );
fs.close();
```

Comment: It's generally better to also tell what your code does differently and why, and not just have an answer with only code and no explanation of how it solves the problem.

Comment: @hyde Generally, I agree.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, to "insert" you have to write to a temporary stream or file. You cannot actively update in the middle.

Lots of STL types support insertion, but it is simulated via behind the scenes processes.

pseudo code:

```
pos = some_int_point_in_file
open(file) as f and open(tmp) as t:
    read f into t until pos then
        insert whatever
    finishing reading the rest of f into t
swap file and tmp
```